# Setting up processing scripts in sub folders in php

Tags: php, ajax, include, directory

I am trying to clean up my website folder structure. I have too many processing scripts in the root directory. The reason is because they won't work if I move them to a sub folder and call them from there.

For eg.

```
root directory
  - images folder
  - css folder
  - js folder
  - includes folder
  - admin folder
index.php
ajax.php
```

Say I move the ajax.php to includes folder, it will look like this.

```
root directory
  - images folder
  - css folder
  - js folder
  - includes folder
    - ajax.php
  - core folder
  - template folder
index.php
```

Now on every page I have an init.php required. In ajax.php for eg.

```
<?php require_once 'core/init.php'; ?>
// rest of the code
```

The issue I am having is that the init.php file won't run as long as ajax.php is in includes folder. I get an error something like this.

```
Warning: require_once(core/init.php): failed to open stream:
```

If i move the ajax.php back to the root directory, it'll work fine.

On index.php, this is how I am calling the ajax.php

```
<a href="includes/ajax.php?id="324"></a>
```

core/init.php works fine when requiring in the "templates" folder.

Perhaps someone can tell me the solution to this?

Comment: You are probably going to get a number of opinions on how best to structure your files.  But you need to decide on your endpoint philosophy.  For example, why would you have any web-accessbile endpoint called `includes/*`?  At that point, is the file really an include or library file or simply an endpoint?  My general philosophy is not to have ANYTHING in the web-accessilbe directory that is not intended to serve as an endpoint, but again, you are going to get a number of opinions here, so this is probably not a good question for SO.

Comment: Understood. Will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using PHP's `chdir` function. This will change the working directory that your PHP environment is working in, and therefore the relative paths that your include functions are looking in. Ideally, you'd want to call `chdir` with the root of your project, so that when you do `require_once('core/init.php');` you don't end up calling from the `core` directory, but rather your `.` directory.

Comment: Great. I will check that function out.  Thanks.